# Java | Webservices WSDL validation error

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, myeclipse

I have successfully built and deployed a jax-ws webservice on myecplise with java 5 and tomcat 5.0 but when I try to create a webservice client I'm getting a validation error on the validation screen

```
WS-I: A problem occurred while running the WS-I WSDL conformance check: org.eclipse.wst.wsi.internal.analyzer.WSIAnalyzerException. The WS-I Test Assertion Document(TAD) was not found or could not be processed. The WSDLAnalyzer was not able to validate the given WSDL file.
```

even if I ignore the case myecplise doesn't allow me to create the client.

Ignore screen #01

```
src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name
'impl:Arrayof_tns1_MatchingDoc' to a(n) 'type definition' component
```

Ignore screen #02

```
src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 
'soapenc:Array' to a(n) 'type definition component
```

After ignoring the 2 screens it gives me an error

```
undefined simple or complex type 'soapenc:Array'
```

and exist the wizard...

Comment: Are you able to post the WSDL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error mentioning `soapenc:Array` may occur if you are trying to compile the **WSDL of a RPC encoded webservice** that is **generated by Axis1**. At least that was the case for me. 
This was a real pain, because there is no way to compile this WSDL with `wsconsume` or even with `wsdl2java` bundled with a Axis2 distribution or with `xfire`. 
I ended up **downloading the [1.4 release ofAxis1](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/ws/axis/1_4) and using the bundled WSDL2java**. You will have to call it from inside the axis.jar as `org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java`. The most comfortable way for that IMHO is to run the .jar from eclipse using arguments in a run configuration.
Unfortunately this is not the end of the story as the generated classes have a tendency to come out with errors (like duplicate methods and such) which you will have to fix manually. So be careful when integrating the WSDL2java task into you ant build.